# React - Create a form with alert and setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, alert, setinterval

I'm trying to do the following exercise with React. It's a basic exercise (I'm learning) but I don't know where to start and don't know how to check the email and password. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Create a form that gets email and password and a component with an alert initially not visible. When submit it should check in an array of users if the email exists and if so, if the corresponding password is correct.

If email and password are correct you should display a positive message with a green background otherwise negative message and red background but in both cases a series of messages:

```
This message will disappear in 3
This message will disappear in 2
This message will disappear in 1
This message will disappear in 0
```

and make the alert component invisible again i.e. unmount it.

> Use `setInterval` to display every message for 1 second

Answer (score 0):

You can use component state to achieve it.

```js
const SomeComponent = ({}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = '';
  const [password, setPassword] = '';
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Same way as password field, and use setInterval to change the state then display.